# Why does link_libraries(stdc++fs) work but not -lstdc++fs?

Tags: c++, cmake, g++, c++17

I was trying to compile a C++17 program on Ubuntu using CMake/g++ 8.1 which contained

```
#include <filesystem>
```

When I used this

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-lstdc++fs")
```

I got a weird linker error

```
undefined reference to `std::filesystem::__cxx11::recursive_directory_iterator::~recursive_directory_iterator()'
```

This error also appeared when I tried calling g++ manually with the `-lstdc++fs` flag.

On the other hand, this line worked as I expected

```
link_libraries(stdc++fs)
```

I'm curious as to why these two lines provide different results. Does the `link_libraries()` function use some magic I'm not aware of?

Comment: What do you mean by manually?

Comment: Did you have to do that? Can you post your CMakeLists.txt? Did you tried a minimal example?

Answer (score 6):

This changes the compiler flags, but not the link flags:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-lstdc++fs")
```

This means that when you compile the file, you add the library, which has no effect, and then when you link to create your executable, you **don't** get this flag.

So you should actually change the linker with:

```
target_link_libraries(target PRIVATE stdc++fs)
```

instead of `link_libraries` (which is old style CMake and is not great at handling multiple targets).

`target_link_libraries` is advised as it only adds the library to `target`. `PRIVATE` also indicates not to propagate the link for shared libraries (i.e. dependent libraries will not link against `stdc++fs`).

You can check the difference in behavior between the two by doing:

```
VERBOSE=1 make
```