# error C2039: 'is_directory': is not a member of 'std::experimental::filesystem' when using CMake in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, cmake, nmake

I am building a project using nmake in Windows
The CMakeLists.txt (abridged) is

```
project(SimManager CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -G"NMake Makefiles")

add_executable(SimManager 
    Source/main.cpp
    )


target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE stdc++fs)

set_target_properties (SimManager PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 17
    CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED TRUE
    CXX_EXTENSIONS FALSE
    )
```

when running from build folder
cmake -G"NMake Makefiles" ..
nmake
I get the error:

`error C2039: 'is_directory': is not a member of 'std::experimental::filesystem'`

Following some suggestions online
[Why does link_libraries(stdc++fs) work but not -lstdc++fs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53801547/why-does-link-librariesstdcfs-work-but-not-lstdcfs)
I used this flag `stdc++fs` in target_link_libraries but the error still doesn't go away

Why is this not working and what is missing?

Additionally, I still have to type in `cmake -G"NMake Makefiles" ..` if I just type in `cmake ..` it builds a visual studio solution

But I have the compile flag already set using line

`set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -G"NMake Makefiles")`

why is it not recognizing the flag that I have set?
Thanks

Comment: Well I think the answer to your second qestion is that `-G"NMake Makefiles"` is not a flag for the compiler it's a flag for cmake itself. According to the documentation you can set the environment variable `CMAKE_GENERATOR` as an alternative to specifying this value on the command line.

Comment: Please, show your C++ code. Currently it smells like you forgot corresponded `#include`, like in that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52470593/stdfilesystemcreate-directories-visual-studio-2017

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you might be trying to use `is_directory` from a `directory_iterator`, for example? If so then you need to use the free function `is_directory` which takes a `file_status` argument which you can get from the iterator's `status()` function. However, fyi, on Windows if you're building with the msbuild toolchain, you can use `std::filesystem` directly which *has* that function in the iterator...